# Building a regular expression to match the first of multiple occurrences in Python

Tags: python, regex

Say I have the following text:

```
*<string1>*<string2>*<string3>*
```

where `*` indicates any text except things surrounded by `<>`.

I would like to be able to capture `string1` (the first occurrence of text wrapped by the characters `<>`).

I have tried using:

```
r = re.compile('.*<(.*?)>.*(<.*?>)*.*')
r.search(my_text)
match = m.group(1)
```

but it didn't work.

I have no problem capturing `string1` with a simpler regular expression if the text has only one occurrence of strings surrounded by `<>` with:

```
r = re.compile('.*<.*?>.*')
```

But I can't identify the correct regexp when the text has multiple regular expressions. I am not sure I am understanding the role of `()` and `?` for this problem correctly.

How would you capture the first `string1` in the top example above?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to parse html/xml with regular expressions. Would you like some help? :)

Comment: @gnibbler. This is not `html` nor `xml`. It's output produced by the shell command `bjobs` in [Platform LSF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_LSF)

Comment: Have you taken a look at [finditer](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.finditer)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it

```
re.search("<([^>]*)", the_string).group(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
import re

my_text = "*<string1>*<string2>*<string3>*"
r = re.compile('(?<=\<)[^>]*')

print r.search(my_text).group(0)

print r.findall(my_text) #This will get an array of all matches.
```

The `(?<=\<)` is a lookbehind, meaning check for matching, but don't capture